# Expandable ListView inside a RecyclerListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview

How to place an Expandable ListView inside a RecyclerView ListView how to do this?
Like this

without Expanding ExpandingListView

[image]

with expanding Expanding ExpandableListView

[image]

used Expandable Listview inside RecyclerView.

all are working fine but while expanding we cannot view the child items when given height as wrap content in Recycler view item height.

to view the same given a fixed height for Recyclerview item height, but it is not efficient.

any other method to do this?
Thanks in advance

Main RecyclerView Adapter

```
 public class MySnatchitsListAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MySnatchitsListAdapterNew.SnatchitViewHolder> {

            Context context;
            ArrayList<Promotion> snatchitslist = new ArrayList<>();
            LayoutInflater inflater;
            AdapterInterface adapterInterface;
            boolean isworkinginbackground = false;
            SimpleTooltip tooltip;

            public void setIsworkinginbackground(boolean isworkinginbackground) {
                this.isworkinginbackground = isworkinginbackground;
            }

            public MySnatchitsListAdapterNew(Context context, ArrayList<Promotion> snatchitslist, AdapterInterface adapterinterface) {

                this.context = context;
                this.snatchitslist = snatchitslist;
                this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.adapterInterface = adapterinterface;
            }

            @Override
            public SnatchitViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_snatchit_list_item_new, null, false);
                return new SnatchitViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final SnatchitViewHolder holder, int position) {

                Promotion item = snatchitslist.get(position);

                CommonUtils.loadProductImage(context, item.getPromotionImage(), R.drawable.no_product_image, R.drawable.no_product_image, holder.img_product);

                holder.swtch_continue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                holder.swtch_continue.setChecked((item.getIsDiscontinued() == 0));

                holder.txt_view_count.setText(item.getViewcount() + "");
                holder.txt_purchase_count.setText(item.getPurchasecount() + "");

               holder.adapter = new ProductExpandableListAdapter(context,snatchitslist.get(position));
                holder.exp_products.setAdapter(holder.adapter);


                if (item.isdiscontinueinprogress()) {

                    holder.pb_discontinue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.swtch_continue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                } else {

                    holder.pb_discontinue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.swtch_continue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.swtch_continue.setTag(position);

                    if (item.isdeleting() || (isworkinginbackground)) {

                        holder.swtch_continue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                buttonView.setChecked(!isChecked);
                                CommonUtils.showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.operation_in_progress));

                            }
                        });

                    } else {

                        holder.swtch_continue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                int pos = (int) buttonView.getTag();

                                adapterInterface.doAction(MySnatchitsFragment.DISCONTINUE_PROMOTION, pos, isChecked);

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

                holder.llyt_my_snatchit.setTag(position);
                holder.llyt_my_snatchit.setTag(R.id.key_holder, holder);
                holder.llyt_my_snatchit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (!isworkinginbackground) {

                            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                            SnatchitViewHolder holder = (SnatchitViewHolder) v.getTag(R.id.key_holder);
                            getQRCodeDetails(holder, pos);

                        } else {
                            CommonUtils.showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.operation_in_progress));
                        }

                    }
                });


                holder.btn_post.setTag(position);
                holder.btn_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                        Promotion item = snatchitslist.get(pos);

                        if ((isworkinginbackground) || (item.isdeleting()) || (item.isdiscontinueinprogress())) {

                            CommonUtils.showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.operation_in_progress));

                        } else {

                            adapterInterface.doAction(MySnatchitsFragment.POST_PROMOTION, pos);

                        }
                    }
                });





            public void hideToolTip() {

                if ((tooltip != null) && (tooltip.isShowing())) {

                    tooltip.dismiss();

                }
            }

            public boolean istooltipshowing() {

                boolean isshowing = false;

                if ((tooltip != null) && (tooltip.isShowing())) {

                    isshowing = true;

                }

                return isshowing;
            }



            public class SnatchitViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


                ImageView img_product;
                Switch swtch_continue;
                Button btn_post;
                LinearLayout llyt_my_snatchit;
                ProgressBar pb_discontinue;
                TextView txt_view_count, txt_purchase_count;
                ImageView img_view_count, img_purchase_count;
                ExpandableListView exp_products;
                ProductExpandableListAdapter adapter ;

                public SnatchitViewHolder(View itemView) {

                    super(itemView);
                    img_product = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_product);
                    swtch_continue = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swtch_continue);
                    btn_post = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
                    llyt_my_snatchit = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llyt_my_snatchit);
                    pb_discontinue = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pb_discontinue);
                    txt_view_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_count);
                    txt_purchase_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_purchase_count);
                    img_view_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_count);
                    img_purchase_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_purchase_count);
                    exp_products = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_products);


                }
            }
        }
```

layout - my_snatchit_list_item_new

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/llyt_my_snatchit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_product"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/product_image_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/no_product_image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/exp_products"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:groupIndicator="@null"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </ExpandableListView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_view_count"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/camera" />

                            <com.integral.app.snatchit.ui.FontTextView

                                android:id="@+id/txt_view_count"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/form_text_color"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />


                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_purchase_count"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/bag" />

                            <com.integral.app.snatchit.ui.FontTextView

                                android:id="@+id/txt_purchase_count"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/form_text_color"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />


                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.integral.app.snatchit.ui.FontButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_post"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_small"
                        android:background="@drawable/post_background"
                        android:elevation="2dp"
                        android:minWidth="0dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/post"
                        android:textColor="@color/clickable_white_text_color" />


                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

                            >

                            <Switch
                                android:id="@+id/swtch_continue"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:textOff="no"
                                android:textOn="yes"
                                android:thumb="@drawable/swith_thumb"
                                android:track="@drawable/swith_track"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/pb_discontinue"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inner Expandable ListView Adapter - ProductExpandableListAdapter

```
package com.integral.app.snatchit.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.integral.app.snatchit.R;
import com.integral.app.snatchit.model.Product;
import com.integral.app.snatchit.model.Promotion;
import com.integral.app.snatchit.util.CommonUtils;

/**
 * Created by sanoop on 23-01-2018.
 */

public class ProductExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


    Context context;
    Promotion promotion;


    public ProductExpandableListAdapter(Context context, Promotion promotion) {

        this.context = context;
        this.promotion = promotion;

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        int childcount = (promotion.getProducts().size() - 2);

            return (childcount<0)? 0 :  childcount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return promotion;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return promotion.getProducts().get(childPosition + 2);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_snatchit_product_item_header, null, false);
            ProductHeaderViewHolder holder = new ProductHeaderViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        ProductHeaderViewHolder holder = (ProductHeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if (promotion.getProducts().size() > 0) {

            Product firstproduct = promotion.getProducts().get(0);
            holder.txt_product_name_1.setText(firstproduct.getProductName());
            String currencysymbol = CommonUtils.getCurrencySymbol(promotion.getCurrencyCode());
            holder.txt_local_price_1.setText(currencysymbol + firstproduct.getProductPriceLocal());
            holder.txt_international_price_1.setText(currencysymbol + firstproduct.getProductPriceInternational());
        }

        if (promotion.getProducts().size() > 1) {

            holder.llyt_product_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Product firstproduct = promotion.getProducts().get(1);
            holder.txt_product_name_2.setText(firstproduct.getProductName());
            String currencysymbol = CommonUtils.getCurrencySymbol(promotion.getCurrencyCode());
            holder.txt_local_price_2.setText(currencysymbol + firstproduct.getProductPriceLocal());
            holder.txt_international_price_2.setText(currencysymbol + firstproduct.getProductPriceInternational());


        } else {

            holder.llyt_product_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (promotion.getProducts().size() > 2) {

            holder.img_show_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.img_show_more.setImageResource(isExpanded ? R.drawable.drop_up : R.drawable.drop_down);

        } else {

            holder.img_show_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_snatchit_product_item_child, null, false);
            ProductChildViewHolder holder = new ProductChildViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        ProductChildViewHolder holder = (ProductChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Product childproduct = promotion.getProducts().get(childPosition+2);

        holder.txt_product_name.setText(childproduct.getProductName());
        String currencysymbol = CommonUtils.getCurrencySymbol(promotion.getCurrencyCode());
        holder.txt_local_price.setText(currencysymbol + childproduct.getProductPriceLocal());
        holder.txt_international_price.setText(currencysymbol + childproduct.getProductPriceInternational());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }


    public class ProductHeaderViewHolder {

        TextView txt_product_name_1, txt_local_price_1, txt_international_price_1, txt_product_name_2, txt_local_price_2, txt_international_price_2;
        FrameLayout flyt_remove;
        ProgressBar pb_remove;
        LinearLayout llyt_product_2;
        ImageView img_show_more;


        public ProductHeaderViewHolder(View itemview) {

            txt_product_name_1 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name_1);
            txt_product_name_2 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name_2);
            txt_local_price_1 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_local_price_1);
            txt_local_price_2 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_local_price_2);
            txt_international_price_1 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_international_price_1);
            txt_international_price_2 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_international_price_2);
            flyt_remove = itemview.findViewById(R.id.flyt_remove);
            pb_remove = itemview.findViewById(R.id.pb_remove);
            llyt_product_2 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.llyt_product_2);
            img_show_more = itemview.findViewById(R.id.img_show_more);

        }
    }


    public class ProductChildViewHolder {

        TextView txt_product_name, txt_local_price, txt_international_price;


        public ProductChildViewHolder(View itemview) {

            txt_product_name = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
            txt_local_price = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_local_price);
            txt_international_price = itemview.findViewById(R.id.txt_international_price);
        }
    }

}
```

ExpandableListAdapter view not able to include because of body size limitaion.
but it is simple textviews not much complicated ones.

Comment: share adapter code.!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi adapter code added , pls help

Comment: RecyclerView inside another Recycler is better than using ListView inside a RecyclerView

Comment: compile 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.1' 
use this library for expandable layout.!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi checking

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc mean ExpandableRecyclerView inside RecyclerView ?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi spot on . perfect. working well . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.1'` use this library for expandable layout.